# Classify up to similarity all $n\times n$ complex matrices such that $A^n=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> Classify up to similarity all $n\times n$ complex matrices such that $A^n=I$.

I've seen this question for [$n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13640/classification-up-to-similarity-of-complex-n-by-n-matrices).  But I was wondering how to generalize this result.

First $A^n=I$ is diagonalizable.  So it is similar to some diagonalizable matrix.  So it's minimal polynomial is the product of distinct linear factors.

Let $J$ be the Jordan form of $A$.  I believe that all the Jordan blocks should be size one.  Since it is able to be factored into distinct monic polynomials.  This means each root will have multiplicity of $1$.  Hence each Jordan block will be size one.  So $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Why must A have distinct eigenvalues? Consider A=I.

Comment: Consider a $3x3$.  Then $x^3-1=(x-1)(x-\omega)(x+\omega^2)$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the answers, especially khalatnikov's, extend to arbitrary n. Your matrix is, up to similarity, a diagonal matrix in which all diagonal entries are nth roots of unity.

> So A is similar to a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues.

The identity matrix is a trivial solution, but it does not have distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: The answer by Kalashnikov? Sounds dangerous:)

Comment: @acccumulation But aren't the nth roots of unity the eigenvalues?

Comment: @emka Yes, but the eigenvalues aren't necessarily different roots of unity. So all of the eigenvalues are roots of unity, but it's not necessarily the case that all of the roots of unity are eigenvalues.